# Is it Possible to classify dataset using DNN classifier based on Different label values of type String?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a network traffic as CSV file and inside that file all required features and class column (Label Column). But the problem is with the class column of type String and it contents with in the following labels:

'normal','icmp-echo','tcp-syn','udp-flood','httpFlood','slowloris','slowpost','bruteForce

I am trying to classify the network traffic(dataset) based on above labels. Is the n-Class > 2 correct/possible?

Please refer the below snapshot which gives a better understanding of what I'm trying to do.

[First Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izI2y.png)

[Second Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dlhh.png)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do classification using DNN. Here is an [example](http://vprusso.github.io/blog/2016/tensor-flow-neural-net-breast-cancer/) to do breast cancer classification using DNN.

As far as the **String labels** are concerned, you need to do [One Hot Encoding](https://hackernoon.com/what-is-one-hot-encoding-why-and-when-do-you-have-to-use-it-e3c6186d008f) to convert categorical variables into numerical variables. You can use [pandas.get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html)
for this.

#### Example

```
>>> s1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a']
>>> pd.get_dummies(s1)
   a  b  c
0  1  0  0
1  0  1  0
2  0  0  1
3  1  0  0
```